# Android: Press both ImageViews at the same time

Tags: java, android, xml, ontouchlistener, motionevent

I am currently trying to make that you have to press both ImageViews simultaneously to move them to a random position on the screen. Since I can't do it with `OnClickListener` I tried it with the following code example.  After hours of searching for an answer I found this code: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530895/android-simultaneous-button-presses)

```
public class MainClass extends Activity { 
// ...
btn1 = (CustomButton)findViewById(R.id.button_one);
btn2 = (CustomButton)findViewById(R.id.button_one);
btn1.ignoreMotionEvent(true);
btn2.ignoreMotionEvent(true);
// ...

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    if(r1 == null)
    {
        //r1 and r2 are Rect that define the absolute region of the button.
        //They are both defined here to ensure that the everything will be layed out (didn't always work so just for extra "sure-ness" did it here)
    }
    CustomButton btn = null;
    MotionEvent mevent = null;
    switch(event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            int x = (int)event.getX();
            int y = (int)event.getY();
            if(r1.contains(x, y))
            {
                btn = btn1;
            }
            else if(r2.contains(x, y))
            {
                btn = btn2;
            }
            if(btn != null)
            {
                mevent = event;
            }
            break;
    }
    if(btn != null)
    {
        btn.ignoreMotionEvent(false);
        btn.onTouchEvent(mevent);
        btn.ignoreMotionEvent(true);
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
}
```

I googled again for an hour or so and began understanding `OnTouchEvent` and `MotionEvent`. 
My main problem currently is that I don't understand what this means.

```
//r1 and r2 are Rect that define the absolute region of the button.
        //They are both defined here to ensure that the everything will be layed out (didn't always work so just for extra "sure-ness" did it here)
```

**Do I need to somehow define an area of my ImageView by somehow getting its size?**

My own code looks like this.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;

public class GameMode2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    public int startTime = 15000;
    public int interval = 1;
    public int counter;
    boolean neoncircle2Clicked = false;
    boolean neoncircle3Clicked = false;
    boolean restartGame2ButtonClicked = false;
    ImageView neoncircle2;
    ImageView neoncircle3;
    TextView startGame2;
    TextView scoreGM2;
    TextView timerGM2;
    Button restartGame2Button;


    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(startTime, interval) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            final int timeLeft = (int) millisUntilFinished;
            timerGM2.setText(Integer.toString(timeLeft / 1000));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timerGM2.setText("Time is up");
            restartGame2Button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            neoncircle2Clicked = true;
            neoncircle3Clicked = true;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_mode2);

        neoncircle2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.neoncircle2);

        neoncircle3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.neoncircle3);

        startGame2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreGM2);
        scoreGM2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreGM2);
        timerGM2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerGM2);
        restartGame2Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.restartGame2Button);

        restartGame2Button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        restartGame2Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!restartGame2ButtonClicked) {
                    startActivity(getIntent());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        ImageView neocnircle2 = null;
        MotionEvent mEvent = null;
        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                int x = (int) event.getX();
                int y = (int) event.getY();

                if (neoncircle2.contains(x, y)) {
                    //do that and this
                }
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public static Point getDisplaySize (@Nullable GameMode2 context) {
        Point point = new Point();
        WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        manager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(point);
        return point;
    }


    public void setCirclesRandomPosition (ImageView neoncircle2, ImageView neoncircle3) {
        int randomX2 = new Random().nextInt(getDisplaySize(this).x - neoncircle2.getWidth());
        int randomY2= new Random().nextInt(getDisplaySize(this).y - (3 * neoncircle2.getHeight()));

        int randomX3 = new Random().nextInt(getDisplaySize(this).x - neoncircle3.getWidth());
        int randomY3 = new Random().nextInt(getDisplaySize(this).y - (3 * neoncircle3.getHeight()));

        neoncircle2.setX(randomX2);
        neoncircle2.setY(randomY2);

        neoncircle3.setX(randomX3);
        neoncircle3.setY(randomY3);
    }

    public void backToMenuGM2Clicked(View view) {
        Intent intentBackToMenuGM2 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intentBackToMenuGM2);
        this.finish();
    }

    public void onBackPressed () {
        Intent obp2 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(obp2);
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/botGameFragGM2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/neoncircle2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/restartGame2Button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/restartGame2Button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/neoncircle2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/neoncircle3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/restartGame2Button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/restartGame2Button"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/neoncircle2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/neoncircle3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/startGame2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#39FF14"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="Tap the green circle to start!"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/restartGame2Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="Restart Game"
        android:textColor="#39FF14"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scoreGM2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#39FF14"
        android:textSize="200dp"
        android:text=""
        android:alpha=".1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The error in the code is here

```
if (neoncircle2.contains(x, y)) {
      //do that and this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `r1` and `r2` may be a `Rect` Object(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html), and your `neoncircle2` is a `ImageView` Object, there is no function named `contains(int, int)` in `ImageView`.

Comment: I did what you said and I got it slighty working. I created two Rect objects and passed in the widths and heights from my ImagewViews. My main problem is now how to I connect my Rect objecs with my ImageViews? Threre are just two Rect objects with the size of my ImageViews. I want to put them on top of my ImageViews to when I touch my ImageView on screen I touch both at the same time. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `onClickListener` of two view at the same time. Just you have to do is on the click of first view, you have to call `onClick()` for the second view programmatically.You can do it using `view.performClick()`

For example if you have twi view view1 and view2 then you can do like this

```
view1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                      view2.performClick();
                       }
                });
view2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                      view1.performClick();
                       }
                });
```

here on click of any one view, `onClickListener` for both view will call.